# generalized hypergeometric function $_1F_2$: positive?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

I ran into the function 
$$_1F_2\left(n+\frac{1}{2};2 n,n+1;-x^2\right)\\
:=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{m!}\frac{(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2}+1)\cdots(n+\frac{1}{2}+m-1)}{(2n)(2n+1)\cdots(2n+m-1)\times(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)}, $$
where $n>0$ is an integer and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Numerical evidence seems to suggest that this function is non-negative for all such $n$ and $x$, so I am wondering if there is some analytic confirmation of that, but I am a bit stumped as to where to start.

I gather that this specific generalized hypergeometric function is one of the more obscure ones. Is there a reference for this kind of question?

Comment: Hypergeometric functions admit representations as integrals of rational functions and/or simpler hypergeometric functions. I think these definitions are much better suited for investigating positivity than this series expansion.

Comment: If I did not make a mistake, the function is negative e.g. for $n=1, x=3.$
At least with  `f:= (n,x) -> hypergeom([n+1/2],[2*n, n+1], -x^2);` Maple gives
$f(1,3) \approx -0.05878$

Comment: @gammatester indeed it is. I suppose that settles the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica informs me of the unlikely-looking identity
$$ {}_1F_2(n+1/2;2n,n+1;-x^2) = {}_0F_1(;n;-x^2/4) \cdot {}_0F_1(;n+1;-x^2/4) $$
(which presumably can be demonstrated by direct computation of the Cauchy product of the functions on the right). This is in turn equal to a product of Bessel functions,
$$ (x/2)^{1-2n} \Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1) J_{n-1}(x)J_n(x). $$
Since the zeros of Bessel functions interlace, there will be plenty of intervals when this has negative values.

Comment: May I asked how you persuaded Mathematica to give you this identity?

Comment: `HypergeometricPFQ[{n + 1/2}, {2 n, n + 1}, -x^2] // 
  FunctionExpand // FullSimplify` worked for me (v. 10.3.1.0).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `FunctionExpand`.

Comment: It (and its trigonometrical friends `TrigExpand`, `TrigFactor`, `TrigReduce` and `TrigToExp` and `ExpToTrig`, as well as the rather finicky `ComplexExpand`) are all well worth knowing about for manipulating expressions. See `guide/FormulaManipulation` in the help for a list.